# Reproduce a ggpairs plot in Python

Tags: python, correlation, scatter-plot

How can I reproduce the correlation scatterplot matrix in this link with Python? It was generated in R with ggpairs. Here is the code in R:

```
p <- ggpairs(iris, aes(color = Species))+ theme_bw()
# Change color manually.
# Loop through each plot changing relevant scales
for(i in 1:p$nrow) {
  for(j in 1:p$ncol){
    p[i,j] <- p[i,j] + 
        scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07")) +
        scale_color_manual(values=c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))  
  }
}
p
```

And here is the link to the code and the plot:
http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/32-r-graphics-essentials/130-plot-multivariate-continuous-data/
[ggpairs plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trFI1.png)
[ggpairs plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBHZT.png)

Comment: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/scatterplot_matrix.html

Comment: Sorry this is the plot I need to regenerate:
https://www.google.com/search?q=ggpairs+plot&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-qM_70O7rAhUGQ60KHbJlDZUQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1792&bih=888#imgrc=6_td7qCmvOurWM

Comment: If you tried even the slightest you could build it using the link I provided as a starting point.